# Issue Incrementing Dictionary with extracted integer from another file using with open

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have been stuck on this for quite a while and I have done some research and I know it is because of an unhashable issue with the dictionary but honestly, I need help and you guys are the last resort.
basically got a dictionary that holds the value of 0 of the ids that are there. So there is a log file that contains those values so I have used regex to extract them. I have made them into an integer so if I print they would not be a str. What I need is to increment the dictionary with the extracted values so if they are found the value in the dictionary goes up so 1102 if 10 are found the count should be 10, I hope this makes sense, thank you! Code:

```py
def finding_matchedevents():
     eventidnew = {1102: {'count': 0}, 4611: {'count': 0}, 4624: {'count': 0}}
     with open('path', 'r') as matchedid:     
         for each_line in matchedid:
             if 'Matched' in each_line:
                 event = re.findall(r'\d+', each_line)
                 res = list(map(int, event)) 
                 eventidnew[res] = eventidnew[res] + 1
                 print(res)
```

Comment: I would be helpful to have a [mre] of that input file as well

Comment: @Tomerikoo basically got a dictionary which holds the value of 0 of the ids that are there. So there is a log file which contains those values so i have used regex to extract them. I have made them into an integer so if i print they would not be a str. What i need is to increment the dictionary with the extracted values so if they are found the value in the dictionary goes up so 1102 if 10 are found the count should be 10, i hope this makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Yes I understood your question perfectly to begin with. This is why I said that `re.findall` returns a ***list*** and not a single number so you basically need to iterate that list and increment each result. Then you also need to fix the indexing to match your dict's structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` is a ***list*** of the IDs found in each line, and not a single ID. You are using that list to access the dictionary.

In addition, the structure of your dict is `{ID: {'count': count}}` so you need to fix your indexing.

Lastly, to only update the IDs that are already in the dictionary, add a simple check:

```py
def finding_matchedevents():
                 [...]
                 res = list(map(int, event))
                 for num in res:
                     if num in eventidnew:
                         eventidnew[num]['count'] += 1
                 [...]
```

Comment: because i get key error i suppose that is to do with the indexing but i do not know how to fix it, i am sorry

Comment: @JamieJonathan1up What do you want to do with IDs that are in the file but not in the initial dict? Do you expect to add them with a 0 count or ignore them?

Comment: i reposted it since i have been stuck over 3 days LOL and you did not reply after 1hr and its my first time honestly I'm sorry bro for that I did not mean to insult you.

Comment: @JamieJonathan1up No worries about it. See my second comment above. Let me know how to help you

Comment: the file has text e.g Matched Event ID: 1102 i have extracted that number with regex and I want to increment the count to my dictionary so when it goes through the ids then matches then the count goes up depending on how many I hope this makes sense thank you.

Comment: Yes it does. I already understand that. You said you get a key error. That means there are IDs in the file which are not in the dictionary. Can you post a short example of that file? Can you explain what to do if the IDs don't exist in the dictionary?

Comment: File source: evtx_logs/Privilege_Escalation/Sysmon_UACME_39.xml
No match for Event ID: 1
Date and Time: 2021-03-09 01:01:35.282659 
 so as you can see it has no match so they should be ignored
File source: evtx_logs/Privilege_Escalation/Sysmon_UACME_39.xml
No match for Event ID: 7
Date and Time: 2021-03-09 01:01:35.282659

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66689590/edit) that into the question. And please answer my question about the missing IDs...

Comment: so the event id 1 should be ignored as it does not match and the matched id which is in the dictionary is a match so that should be incremented by 1 to the count to show it has been found .

Comment: Another question. Why do you use this structure `{ID: {"count": count}}`? Why not just `{ID: count}`?

Comment: yes you are right as i tried to use nested dict

Comment: Yes, thank you very much bro it works i have checked the log as well as 1102 has 15 and it prints 15 times is there a way in where it does not print 15 times on the terminal but brother honestly thank you bro for your help so far i honestly appreciate it.

Comment: Just remove that `print(res)` line. Instead, add a `print(eventidnew)` ***outside*** the loop.

Comment: Thank you bro it is finally working after wasting 3 days on looking at ways of incrementing and you in the end have helped me with this issue thank you very much bro

Comment: I am really happy to help you ^_^ You shouldn't waste too much time like that. For the future try to research smaller problems. Learn to play around in an interactive Python shell. That could help you understand the nested indexing part

Comment: Honestly, i appropriate your help and i am sorry for making you feel that way earlier was not my intention is there a way I can reward you?

Comment: Really don't feel bad about it. I understand you are new and was frustrated with your problem and just wanted a solution. But please see it from my side. I saw this question and wanted to help and dedicated time and posted an answer, and then some time later I see a title that feels familiar and see that you asked the same question again. This is not the Stack Overflow way in general, but it's also not nice if you already have answers. But again, don't feel bad! No hard feelings. I'm happy I could help you in the end